# Вопрос по Jackson / JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

Как реализовать десериализацию, чтобы полученные объекты пользовались общими Ingredient из List.

```
public class Blueprint {
private String name;
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
}
```

Полный код:

```
List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
ingredients.add(new Ingredient("Water", 1));
ingredients.add(new Ingredient("Flour", 1));
Blueprint bread = new Blueprint("Bread", ingredients);
Blueprint pellet = new Blueprint("Pellet", ingredients);
String breadJson = convertToJson(bread);
String pelletJson = convertToJson(pellet);

Blueprint restoredBread = loadFromJSon(breadJson);
Blueprint restoredPellet = loadFromJSon(pelletJson);
System.out.println(restoredBread);
System.out.println(restoredPellet);
```

Вывод:

```
Blueprint{name='Bread', ingredients=[Ingredient@402f32ff, Ingredient@573f2bb1]}
Blueprint{name='Pellet', ingredients=[Ingredient@5ae9a829, Ingredient@6d8a00e3]}
```

В текущем виде соответственно Jackson создает новые ингредиенты для каждого чертежа, а хотелось бы, что бы он брал чертежи из мапы.

Answer (score 1):

На текущий момент найдено такое решение:
Использовать getInstance в Ingredient, обеспечив тем уникальность.

```
private static Map<String, Ingredient> ingredients = new HashMap<String, Ingredient>();

@JsonCreator
public static Ingredient getInstance(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("volume") double volume) {
    if (ingredients.containsKey(name)) return ingredients.get(name);
    else {
        Ingredient created = new Ingredient(name, volume);
        ingredients.put(name, created);
        return created;
    }
}
```